# How to make recipient address dynamic ,so i can avoid making changes in SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, config

I have SQL task in my SSIS Package which send an db email.

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject=@SUB,
@body=@BODY,
@query= 'SELECT DISTINCT FileLoadName
FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >=@PackageStartTime',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1
```

But the value of @recipients is hard coded here. So i had a quick thought. Each time recipient name change I have to go to SSIS package and apply changes there. Is there any other way to do it, like make it as variable and put it in config file; so if values changes over time, someone can just go ahead and make changes in config file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a parameter. One such example: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/

**Note**: I prefer to receive the passed variables at the beginning of the code. That way, even if my code structure changes, the sequence of parameters being passed would not be required to be altered.

I have not touched the value you have set for the query as I do not understand as to why your parameter @PackageStartTime is within quotes. You can pass that as well the attach flag as parameter.

Once the query has been parameterized, the corresponding variables can be put in the configuration.

```
DECLARE 
    @p_profile_name AS VARCHAR(100) = ?,
    @p_receipients AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ?,
    @p_subject as VARCHAR(100) = ?,
    @p_body AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ?;

    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name= ?, --'default',
    @recipients= ?,                       --'dev@null.com',
    @subject= ?                           -- @SUB,
    @body= ?                              -- @BODY,
    @query= 'SELECT DISTINCT FileLoadName
            FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >=@PackageStartTime',
            @attach_query_result_as_file=1
```

Please let us (the **energetic team of fellow SSIS developer**) know whether it worked.

Comment: Thanks for reply Anoop                                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351282/send-db-mail-task-fails-in-ssis-package-with-errors-related-to-the-parameter

Comment: Can i please have ans of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also get your list of recipients from a table like this. Lets say you have a table named EmployeeList that has an EmailAddress field.

```
DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(500)
SET @emails = '' 
SELECT @emails = @emails + EmailAddress + ';' FROM EmployeeList 

DECLARE @recipList VARCHAR(500)
SET @recipList =  (select SUBSTRING(@emails, 0, LEN(@emails)))
```

And then you can set your recipients list like this

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients= @recipList,
@subject=@SUB,
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

Maina, I looked at your code given on page pertaining to questions/15351282.

1. A general comment: Think in terms of component and how much responsibility you want to assign to them. This is a very important concept/practice for writing clean, manageable, and efficient code.
2. Now some specifics: Inside the code you are executing an if statement and then making a decision whether the email should be sent or not. Split it in two parts. At the control surface have the first Execute sql task. Store the result in a variable. Test just this piece, and make sure that right number of rows are being stored in your package variable. Sorry, if I am being too granular.
3. Use a conditional task to  decide if this sendEmail task should be executed or not.
4. Use a simple query first; remove @attach_query_result_as_file parameter.
5. Add another variable inside this task: DECLARE @p_PackageStartTime as varchar(40);
   @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT FileLoadName FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= ' + @PackageStartTime
6. Make sure, you are passing the parameters in the right order.
   If still fails, please add a screen shot of the parameter mapping.