# Send db mail task fails in SSIS Package with errors related to the parameter

Tags: ssis, resultset, dbmail

I am trying to execute this sql task in SSIS package which send an email when the file name is not found. I have declared this user-defined variable "@PackageStartTime" in my ssis package.  But when my SSIS package hit this task it fails with following error.

"Executing query DECLARE @PackageStartTime Varchar(250) SET @Packag...." failed with the error.: "Parameter name is unrecognized."
Possible failure reasons: Problem with the query, "ResultSet" Property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

```
DECLARE @PackageStartTime Varchar(250)
SET @PackageStartTime =?

IF(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >=@PackageStartTime)>0

BEGIN

DECLARE @SUB Varchar(250)
SET @SUB = 'File Failed'+@@SERVERNAME

DECLARE @BODY Varchar(250)
SET @BODY = 'File Failed'+@@SERVERNAME

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject=@SUB,
@body=@BODY,
@query= 'SELECT DISTINCT FileLoadName
FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >=@PackageStartTime',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1
```

I am unable to understand. I have just added a variable User::strPackageStartTime as Datatype = String and Value is blank. I don't have that variable in parameter mapping in  Execute SQL Task Editor. Is there I am missing something?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure that you cannot pass a parameter into a script like that from SSIS, but you can pass it into a stored procedure. So wrap all of that up in a stored procedure with a parameter. The following code creates your stored procedure.

Then you call it with

```
EXEC p_MyProc ?
```

in your package

Also note I think you set @SUB twice - I changed it to @BODY

**Also please note it is usually a bad idea to store dates as varchar(250) - change it to date or datetime now if you have the opportunity.**

```
CREATE PROC p_MyProc
@PackageStartTime Varchar(250)
AS

IF(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >=@PackageStartTime)>0

BEGIN

DECLARE @SUB Varchar(250)
SET @SUB = 'File Failed'+@@SERVERNAME

DECLARE @BODY Varchar(250)
SET @BODY = 'File Failed'+@@SERVERNAME

EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject=@SUB,
@body=@BODY,
@query= 'SELECT DISTINCT FileLoadName
FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >=@PackageStartTime',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1

GO
```

Comment: I know. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I can't create new stored procedures. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You can move all of the logic in to SSIS

Comment: Since I can't create the stored procedure here. How should i do it? I am sorry I am new to SSIS.

Comment: See my guide in my other answer on how to create this logic in SSIS

Answer (score 0):

To move this into SSIS (please note I do not have access to SSIS so I'm flying blind)

1. Create an execute SQL Task with this in it:

SELECT COUNT(*) As RCount, 'File Failed' + @@SERVERNAME As Msg
FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= ?

1. Pass your parameter in, and capture the result into two variables, (single row returned)
2. Your next step is another execute SQL Task, calling sp_send_dbmail with your variables. This is called conditionally so it only runs if the prior step returned a non zero value